# Suddenly can no longer run Kitematic on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: docker, virtualbox, macos-high-sierra, kitematic

The problem appeared yesterday out of the blue. I installed MacOS High Sierra on my MacBook Pro over a month ago, and there have been no issues--until now. I presume that Kitematic stopped working due to a VirtualBox-related issue; I'd start Kitematic which in turn attempted to start my virtual machine, but bootup would halt at about 45%, with Kitematic telling me that the failure was due to a known VirtualBox bug that could be resolved by installing a newer version of VirtualBox. So, I uninstalled VirtualBox and attempted to install a newer version--again, to no avail. Apparently, there's a known issue involving MacOS High Sierra, VirtualBox, and kexts (something about which I know damn near nothing). I'm completely at a loss, and this issue has completely halted the development of my database. Has anyone else encountered this issue and, if so, have you determined how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

As of may 2018, Kitematic is still broken on MacOS High Siera. 
However the underlying Docker tools are still functional on High Siera. To use them:

Open a terminal window and enter

```
docker images
```

Which will show the docker images you have created previously with Kitematic. Then you start a container using the

```
docker run
```

command. You can see the running containers using the

```
docker ps
```

command. And then open a bash shell in a running container using the:

```
docker exec -it <containerIdOrName> bash
```

command.

If you use docker on a regular basis it is worth while to get familiar with the most common docker terminal commands

Answer (score 0):

For me, killing the process solved the issue.

```
ps -efww | grep -i kitematic
```

to find it. then:

```
kill <pid>
```

or the one line version:

```
ps -efww | grep -i kitematic | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs kill
```